# Failed to read external DTD 'XMLSchema.dtd' - Apache cxf & Spring boot

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, cxf

I'm using Apache-cxf's cxf-codegen-plugin for wsdl2java generation. It was working properly so far but when I've updated my apache-cxf(3.3.1) and spring boot(2.1.3.RELEASE) to the latest version, Maven's started to give me Maven error message:

> Execution generate-sources of goal org.apache.cxf:cxf-codegen-plugin:3.3.1:wsdl2java failed: org.apache.ws.commons.schema.XmlSchemaException: External DTD: Failed to read external DTD 'XMLSchema.dtd', because 'http' access is not allowed due to restriction set by the accessExternalDTD property. (org.apache.cxf:cxf-codegen-plugin:3.3.1:wsdl2java:generate-sources:generate-sources)

I saw that I might need to make some additional configuration about VM and added following tags:

```
<fork>always</fork>
<additionalJvmArgs>-Djavax.xml.accessExternalSchema=all</additionalJvmArgs>
```

but hit a new error:

> Command line was: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java -Djavax.xml.accessExternalSchema=all -jar /tmp/cxf-tmp-4500902427872984708/cxf-codegen118328547383604063.jar -encoding UTF-8 -d /home/tsvetoslav/sts-workspace/smdp1/target/generated/cxf -impl -verbose -wsdlLocation classpath:wsdl/ES3_SMSR.wsdl file:/home/tsvetoslav/sts-workspace/smdp1/src/main/resources/wsdl/ES3_SMSR.wsdl

Finally, here is my plugin:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${cxf.version}</version>
    <configuration>
        <fork>always</fork>
        <additionalJvmArgs>-Djavax.xml.accessExternalSchema=all</additionalJvmArgs>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>generate-sources</id>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <configuration>
                <sourceRoot>${project.build.directory}/generated/cxf</sourceRoot>
                <wsdlOptions>
                    <wsdlOption>
                    <wsdl>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/wsdl/ES3.wsdl</wsdl>
                    <wsdlLocation>classpath:wsdl/ES3.wsdl</wsdlLocation>
                        <extraargs>
                            <extraarg>-impl</extraarg>
                            <extraarg>-verbose</extraarg>
                        </extraargs>
                    </wsdlOption>
                </wsdlOptions>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
                <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Any suggestion, how can I solve the issue?